# Creating a Custom Widget with KivyMD and Python

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, widget, kivymd

I was wondering. If I wanted to create a widget that displays a player's score as shown in the uploaded image, how would I go about that? I understand there's a way to work with texture and icons to get the results but it's just not working for me. I want to be able to use custom images for the icons appearing on the left and right of the widget. Also, I want to be able to increment or decrement the score based on player's activity.[a score widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaSrV.png)

I have read through the docs and on topics like MDLabels and MDDropdownMenu list items but it's just not working.

Here's my code. It works okay, for the most part. However, I can't quite find the widget to put the three widgets (`MDIconButton`, `MDLabel`, `MDIconButton`) inside.
Also, I have commented out this line `text_size: (20, 20)` and
this one `font_size: "40sp"` coz I'm still trying to figure out
how to make them work. If you could help with that too, it would be great.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder


kv = '''

MDScreen:

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: (1, 1)
        spacing: dp(10)
        padding: dp(5)

        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: (1, .06)
            md_bg_color: "orange"

            # I'm not sure why this isn't working
            # I was thinking of putting the three widgets 
            # (MDIconButton, MDLabel, MDIconButton) in here
            # RoundedRectangle:
            #   pos: (5, 1400)
            #   size: (100, 20)
            #   radius: [18, ] * 4

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "language-python"
                _no_ripple_effect: False
                on_release: app.python_message()

            MDLabel:
                id: score
                text: "281"
                # text_size: (20, 20)
                halign: "center"
                font_style: "Button"

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "plus"
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                icon_color: "white"
                md_bg_color: "blue"
                # font_size: "40sp"
                _no_ripple_effect: True
                on_release: app.plus_sign_action()

        MDBoxLayout:
            size_hint: (1, .94)
            md_bg_color: "black"

            MDLabel:
                text: "Other Widgets"
                bold: True
                halign: "center"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "orange"



'''

class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(kv)

        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"

        return self.screen

    def python_message(self, *args):
        pass

    def plus_sign_action(self, *args):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Example().run()
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of what you have tried.

Comment: @JohnAnderson, I edited the code to show the attempts I made. Kindly look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can get a reasonable looking widget by creating a custom widget based on the `MDBoxLayout`. The class could be defined as:

```
class MyCustomWidget(MDBoxLayout):
    # these are the attributes to set in the kv
    left_icon = StringProperty('')
    left_action = ObjectProperty(None)
    text = StringProperty(' ')
    right_icon = StringProperty('')
    right_action = ObjectProperty(None)
```

With a rule for it added to the `kv`:

```
<MyCustomWidget>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    adaptive_size: True  # Use adaptive size
    md_bg_color: "orange"

    MDIconButton:
        icon: root.left_icon
        _no_ripple_effect: False
        on_release: root.left_action() if root.left_action else None

    Label:  # MDLabel gives odd behavior when length of text increases
        text: root.text
        font_size: 40
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.texture_size
        pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.5}

    MDIconButton:
        icon: root.right_icon
        theme_icon_color: "Custom"
        icon_color: "white"
        md_bg_color: "blue"
        _no_ripple_effect: True
        on_release: root.right_action() if root.right_action else None
```

Then, you can use it in your `kv` to replace the `MDBoxLayout`:

```
    MyCustomWidget:
        id: custom
        left_icon: 'language-python'
        left_action: app.python_message
        text: "281"
        right_icon: 'plus'
        right_action: app.plus_sign_action
```

And your `plus_sign_action()` method can modify the score, for example:

```
def plus_sign_action(self, *args):
    score = int(self.root.ids.custom.text)
    score += 1
    self.root.ids.custom.text = str(score)
```